# UK visa refusal because of my economic ties in the Philippines

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I need advice. I want to apply for a one-month UK tourist visa. I’m from the Philippines, a single parent. I have a long-time boyfriend from the UK and he came to visit me twice a year for 5 years already. We also visited some Asian countries together. I’m not employed, I own a house but I don’t own the land because the government allowed me to build my house on this land. I stopped working abroad because he wants me to visit his country and to meet her parents as well... I’m doing an apparel online business, and I own a tricycle, which I’m using for private service for students in my place.

Apart from that, my boyfriend supports me and my son's needs. Which documents do I need to apply for a visa? I was refused a year ago, they questioned my economic ties in the Philippines.

Comment: Do you file taxes and other paperwork for your online and tricycle businesses?

Comment: I don’t have any taxes for my online, I only have DTI and barangay permit for that because I’m just posted the items  in my Facebook page. It’s not a passenger tricycle tho, I’m just using it for private service. But I have complete papers for tricycle when I bought it.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem like it will be enough to demonstrate economic ties.

Comment: Thanks sir. How about my boyfriend remittances. And I have my son here in Philippines and I need to come back. He is 10 yrs old only, and studying. I’m planning to travel to U.K.  on November and comeback on December because we will bring my son to hongkong for Christmas holiday?

Comment: The remittances aren't something that tie you to the Philippines. I'm afraid you'll need to consult a UK immigration lawyer.